# How to reshape data in pandas to plot with Choropleth

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape, choropleth

I'm trying to plot with Choropleth some data (particularly this dataset from GitHub ([terrorism in EU countries](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/terrorism/eu_terrorism_fatalities_by_country.csv)).

I have something like this:

```
year  country1  countr2 country3
1970  10        20      30  
1971  40        50      60    
1972  70        80      90
```

And as far as I know, should have something like this:

```
year  country   value
1970  country1  10
1970  country2  20
1970  country3  30
1971  country1  40
1971  country2  50
1971  country3  60
1972  country1  70
1972  country2  80
1972  country3  90
```

How can I achieve this with Pandas? Is this a good approach to solve the problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of tasks are just a pice of bamboo to Pandas :)

And you just need to [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking) your DataFrame:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> # First you need to make `iyear` as index when reading csv to DataFrame.
>>> df = pd.read_csv('eu_terrorism_fatalities_by_country.csv', index_col=0)
>>> df.iloc[0:5, 0:3] # Take a look
       Belgium  Denmark  France
iyear                          
1970         0        0       0
1971         0        0       0
1972         0        0       1
1973         0        0       5
1974         0        0       3
>>> res = df.stack() # Just this simple :D
>>> res.head() # That's it.
iyear         
1970   Belgium    0
       Denmark    0
       France     0
       Germany    0
       Greece     2
dtype: int64
```

Note that the result `res` is a *MultiIndex Series*, and some follow-ups:

```
>>> res.index.names = ['year', 'country']
>>> res.name = 'value'
>>> res.head()
year  country
1970  Belgium    0
      Denmark    0
      France     0
      Germany    0
      Greece     2
Name: value, dtype: int64
>>> res.to_csv('results.csv', header=True)
```

In the `results.csv` file:

```
year,country,value
1970,Belgium,0
1970,Denmark,0
1970,France,0
... ...
2014,Portugal,0
2014,Spain,0
2014,United Kingdom,0
```

---

Follow up your comment, if you want to turn the MultiIndex Series `res` into a DataFrame, just [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html#pandas.Series.reset_index) and control the behavior with it's args:

```
>>> flat = res.reset_index()
>>> flat.head()
   year  country  value
0  1970  Belgium      0
1  1970  Denmark      0
2  1970   France      0
3  1970  Germany      0
4  1970   Greece      2
>>> flat2 = res.reset_index(level=1)
>>> flat2.head()
      country  value
year                
1970  Belgium      0
1970  Denmark      0
1970   France      0
1970  Germany      0
1970   Greece      2
```

Comment: Thanks for your great explanataion! I managed to find the stack() method but as you stated it returns a Series. Following your indications I could write the resulting CSV file and then re-import it again into a new DataFrame. But I wonder if there is a way to avoid this step and get a DataFrame from the stacked data directly. In other words, how can I convert a series (in which each element represents 3 columns) to a DataFrame?

Comment: @juancar That's also very simple :) Take a look at the edited answer.